# Can you get an session attribute from a servlet in a <% %> block in a jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, web

Can I get a session attribute from a Servlet in a

```
<%

%>
```

block within a jsp?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
session.getAttribute("name");
to print 
<%= session.getAttribute("name"); %>
```

And to set them in servlet use

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    session.setAttribute("name", name);
```